# login api of an npm package "5paisajs" not working

Tags: node.js, api, npm

I am trying to login using 5paisa api but getting the message as invalid input parameters.Have check the configurations several times there seem to be no problem with configuration. The API code snippet is here:

```
const conf = {
    "appSource": "****",
    "appName": "5P5....",
    "userId": "FEVg----",
    "password": "6a5--Satj",
    "userKey": "------7YjaIxqjqcUzBGjjj",
    "encryptionKey": "-------lQfp34AX5memHkeq909"
}
const { FivePaisaClient } = require("5paisajs")

var client = new FivePaisaClient(conf)
 client.login("abcd@gmail.com", "abcd#12345", "yyyymmdd").then(
        (response) => {
        
            console.log(response)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            return res.json({
                eror: err
            })
        })
```

Comment: https://github.com/5paisa/5paisa-js/issues/new